# Not able to call dependent test cases

Tags: phpunit

I am writing the unit tests to test a Model class. 
First I have a `testAddStudent()` test case that adds some data to db.
Then I have another test case to retrieve the record I just added.
The code I  have looks like the following:

```
class Model_STest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

protected $_student;

public function setUp() {
    error_log("Entered setup");
    parent::setUp();

    $this->_student = new Application_Model_Student();
}

public function testInit() {
    error_log("Entered testInit");
}

public function testAddStudent() {
    error_log("Entered testAddStudent");
    $testData = array(
            'name' => 'abc',
            'teacher' => 'amyac',
            'start_date' => '2012_08_06'
            );

    $result = $this->_student->addStudent($testData);
    error_log("result is ".print_r($result, true));
    $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $result);
}

/**
 * @depends testAddStudent
 */
public function testGetStudent($result) {
    error_log("Entered testGetStudent, finding student id: $result");
    $resultx = $this->_student->getStudent($result);
    $this->assertEquals($result, $resultx);
    }

}
```

However, when I run the phpunit test (using command line), The logs show me that the student id being searched is 0. Whereas the `testAddStudent` is returning me the student id as a non-zero value.

What am I doing wrong? 
I have

> PHPUnit 3.6.11 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return `$result` from your `testAddStudent()` function.

(The returned value from the depended-on function is passed to depending function.)

You might also consider doing the same with your Application_Model_Student instance, instead of using a protected class variable. Here is your example rewritten to show that. (I used a dummy Application_Model_Student that does just enough to pass the test.)

```
class Application_Model_Student{
private $d;
function addStudent($d){$this->d=$d;return 1;}
function getStudent($ix){return $ix;}
}

//----------------------
class Model_STest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

public function testAddStudent() {
    error_log("Entered testAddStudent");

    $testData = array(
            'name' => 'abc',
            'teacher' => 'amyac',
            'start_date' => '2012_08_06'
            );

    $student = new Application_Model_Student();
    $result = $student->addStudent($testData);
    error_log("result is ".print_r($result, true));
    $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $result);
    return array($student,$result);
}

/**
 * @depends testAddStudent
 */
public function testGetStudent($data) {
    list($student,$result)=$data;
    error_log("Entered testGetStudent, finding student id: $result");
    $resultx = $student->getStudent($result);
    $this->assertEquals($result, $resultx);
    }

}
```

P.S. Note the implementation I used for `getStudent` to get it to pass! I imagine this is not the test you intended to do.

Comment: You've provided the correct solution to the problem, but I don't recommend reusing the model fixture. Each unit test should be as independent as is practical. Otherwise you risk having the first test alter the model in such a way that it interferes with the second test.

Comment: Darren and @DavidHarkness, thank you for replying. Darren, I am only using return $result and that did pass the value to the testGetStudent function. However, it throws an error saying >Zend_Db_Table_Row Object (...) does not match expected type "string". Even though the model function getStudent($result) ran fine and it could get the rec_id in Zend_Db_Table_Row Object format, the assert fails due to this error. Am I missing something else?

Comment: And for the getStudent() function, I did not really understand what is the motive behind implementing in that way. As of now, I am creating the model object in the setup, so every time a test case is run, the set up will have a clean model object. If you could please elaborate why is the current implementation wrong and why it should be implemented the way you did it, that will be great. Thanks again.

Comment: @Parminder I prefer to pass all _dependent data_ using the depends mechanism; your example appeared to show passing half of it (result) using the depends mechanism, but passing the other half (a student object) using a member variable. But perhaps I misunderstood what your code does? I was assuming `Application_Model_Student` stores data. But if it is just a handle to a database connection then there is no need. (But in that case I still wouldn't use `setUp()`; I'd instead move the `$student = new Application_Model_Student();` line into every function that needs it. Just for code clarity.

Comment: @DarrenCook - My guess is that `Application_Model_Student` operates as a [Data Access Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object).

Comment: @DavidHarkness and Darren Yes, the Model communicates to the db and gets the results. Darren I did not call the $student = new Application_Model_Student() line into every function that needs it because in phpUnit documentation I read about fixtures and it reads ..  > We can now refactor Example 4.1 and use setUp() to eliminate the code duplication that we had before. [link](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.3/en/phpunit-book.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit). That was the main reason that I moved the `new` call to setup.

Comment: Appreciate your taking time to explain the solution. Thank you so much.